# Detect a captive portal on iOS

Tags: ios, networking

So I'm able to detect whether or not the user has basic internet connection fine using Apple's reachability class. However, when I try to detect whether or not they are connected to a Wi-Fi network that utilizes a captive portal, I get back `NetworkStatusReachableViaWiFi`, which makes sense. However, this will also be returned if the user is simply using a WiFi connection.

I need to be able to detect both no internet connection and the captive portal situation, as that is effectively no internet.

Are there any reliable API's that can accomplish this task? Based off this article, http://blog.erratasec.com/2010/09/apples-secret-wispr-request.html#.VxkmrJMrIy5, Apple pings an internal address when you connect to WiFi to check for a captive portal. I'd prefer to avoid pinging any outside networks, however if I must, does anyone know how I could ping the same Apple address and use the response to tell if my user has a captive portal up?

Edit: I've come across `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and its method `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`. I think this method may be able to do what I need, I can send a basic request to www.google.com and make myself the delegate, and if this method gets hit do what I need to do. I think I would then be able to call `cancelAuthenticanChallenge:`

Has anyone ever used this method before to detect a captive portal? How did it work?

Comment: Send an HTTP request and validate the response. Did get an HTTP 200 back? Validate the response body as well. If things don't match, you're likely on a limited connection - e.g. restricted by a captive portal. Furthermore, a ping request (ICMP protocol) doesn't help because some networks using captive portals block HTTP, while they don't block ICMP, and eventually HTTPS.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with that method is that I'm then relying on a third party to check for a captive portal. What if that website goes down? What if they change how they respond to a request? What if they start sending HTTP error codes back that match the ones for captive portal for general errors? There's a lot of unknown variables when working with a third party server who doesn't know or expect you to be using them for the purpose I am. I'd prefer another way - if possible.

Comment: You can use http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html - if that goes down, then Apple WISPr requests won't work either. If you don't trust that, you can always host a text file on [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), and request that file via its public URL. It should never go down, unless AWS goes down. Quoting [AWS S3 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/): `S3 Standard is designed for 99.99% availability and Standard - IA is designed for 99.9% availability. Both are backed by the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement.`